# sIFR and RTL Languages

Tags: right-to-left, sifr

Does sIFR support RTL Languages? And if it does is there any additional configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine if you are targeting Flash 10 or higher: [Adobe Labs Note about Advanced Text Layout](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/).

Answer (score 0):

sIFR 3 is based on Flash 8 which does not have support for RTL. Not sure if it can easily be modified to do so.